# How to avoid type error in this case, when the application is closed?

Tags: python, queue, readfile, readlines

I have the following code, but when I exit from the application, I get:
"**TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not NoneType**"
The thing is I get the hostnames from a Queue, how to solve this to dont get error? Otherwise it is doing its job.

```py
hostname = self.queue.get()
with open("allhosts.txt", "r") as f:
    if hostname in f.read():
        self.found.emit(hostname)
    else:
        self.notFound.emit(hostname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error you mentioned it should be happening when `self.queue.get()` is coming as `None`. So you may need to have an if condition to check if `hostname` is present or not before proceeding to checking inside the file.